# Why is the topological space of reals defined to be path connected?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Note: $R$ is the topological space of reals, equipped with the standard topology.

A set $X$ is said to be path connected if there exists a continuous map, $f:R \to X$, such that for <del>any</del> $r_1,r_2 \in R$, with $r_1<r_2$, we have $f(r_1) = x$ and $f(r_2) = y$ and $x,y \in X$.

This seems like we are defining the topology on reals, $R$ to be path connected, by definition, as there always exists a <del>homo</del>morphism $f:R \to R$ and we are trying to extend this notion to other topological spaces $X$, through the continuous map $f:R \to X$.

It seems like, we could consider any connected space $Y$ and define it to be path connected. Then call $X$ to be path connected if there exists a continuous map $f:Y \to X$ satisfying the above conditions.

It seems like we are interested only in the topologies which are <del>homo</del>morphic to $R$. Why is a special preference given to the topology on reals?

Edit: It was pointed out by Jose Carlos Santos that my definition of path connectedness is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of path-connected is worst than wrong: it desn't make sense. How can we have $f(r_1)=x$ and $f(r_2)=y$ for *any* $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb R$? Even assuming that $r_1\neq r_2$.

The usual definition of path-conneced is: $X$ is path-connected if, for any $x,x'\in X$, there is a continuous map from some interval $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb R$ (with $a<b$) into $X$ such that $f(a)=x$ and that $f(b)=x'$. But $f$ usually is *not* a homeomorphism. Acutally, it doesn't even have to be a homeomorphism from $[a,b]$ onto $f\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$, since $f$ might not be one-to-one.

Comment: The question still has a point. Why do we when defining path-connectedness require the functions domain to be an interval and not some other space. I guess the homotopy groups are a generalization of this, where the domains are spheres. Are there any other examples?

Comment: I have changed the definition now. I am referring to homomorphism, not homeomorphism i.e. structure preserving maps, which are not necessarily invertible. This leads to me to another question. Does it even make sense to talk about homomorphisms for topologies?

Comment: @u6844 Homomorphisms ser for groups. In the context of Topology, what we have are homeomorphisms.

Comment: Could you elaborate why we don't have homomorphisms for topologies? I am not a math student, so I may be getting the terminology wrong. From what I know, for objects in a category, homomorphisms are the "arrows" of the category, which preserve that structure of objects.

Comment: @u6844 No. Homomorphisms are for groups or, morge generally for algebraic structures (rings, for instance). It's just a matter of definition, but the fact is that, in Topolgy, what we have are homeomorphisms, whch are those bijective continuous maps whose inverses are alse continuous.

Comment: It seems, I'm talking about morphisms, not homomorphisms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism

Comment: @u6844 Well, the continuous maps are the morphisms of the category of topological spaces.

Answer (score 0):

(Concerning your definition of path connected see José Carlos Santo's answer.)

"Path connected" is the most intuitive description of connectedness, and is easy to work with, e.g., it allows to pull back functions defined on a large and "complicated" space to a real interval. A large part of spaces and domains occurring in analysis or geometry are in fact path connected.

Of course there are situations where we have to recurse to the more subtle "official" description of connectedness, e.g., when dealing with the set
$$S:=\left\{(x,y)\>\biggm|\>x\ne0\ \wedge\ y=\sin{1\over x}\right\}\cup \bigl(\{0\}\times[{-1},1]\bigr)\subset{\mathbb R}^2\ .$$
The "official" definition, when it has to be applied to relative spaces, as in the above example, can be quite delicate. Therefore we are glad when a set under study is not only connected but even path connected.